# AWS Cognito obtain/override deviceKey in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to write a node.js REST wrapper for AWS cognito. I want the client to supply a `deviceKey` which Cognito will use to detect if the user is logging in from a new device.

I'm wondering how you can obtain the `deviceKey` of a client, and also supply a custom `deviceKey` when trying to authenticate.

Something like the following:

```
const AWS.getDeviceKey({
    onSuccess: (deviceIdentifier) => deviceIdentifier
})

const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
    DeviceKey: "client identifier string"
})

cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: (result) => result
})
```

Comment: I do not know how to get the device key in a node.js environment, but I recently figured it out for the browser environment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57290452/2300770
Maybe this helps figuring out a solution for node.js.

Answer (score 0):

That is already taken care by the SDK. Basically the SDK retrieves the deviceKey from the configured storage. If there is a device key, it will pass it on in the calls for authentication, the service will recognize it as a device key it has seen before and it will issue a challenge for a DEVICE_PASSWORD_VERIFIER that the SDK must complete.

In case there is no device key passed (new device case), upon finishing authentication, the service issues a NewDeviceMetadata object that the SDK can call confirmDevice with to register this new device. The deviceKey retrieved in the NewDeviceMetadata is then stored locally so that on new logins, it will not consider this as a new device.